# Why my GPU resources unused when running games?

Tags: nvidia, games, nvidia-optimus, gpu

My laptop is experiencing hard times running games, the frames are constantly freezes and twitches. I decided to have a look at my CPU and GPU memory usage, where I saw disappointingly stats, which led me to question: **why more than half of my GPU resources idling?**

My specs

```
Laptop: Aspire V3-771 V2.23
CPU: Intel i3-3110M (4) @ 2.400GHz  
GPU: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M
```

If I understand correctly, GPU should go into full usage and then, if game demands more memory and it comes near to overflow GPU memory it unloads into swap. When I'm playing almost 8-year old steam game I have the following status of my system:

**Nvidia X server settings**

```
Total Memory:           4096 MB
Total Dedicated Memory: 4039 MB
Used Dedicated Memory:  411MB(14%)  <-- Not even a half
```

**Htop**

```
RAM  1.7GB / 7.3GB
SWAP 0GB / 8GB
CPU1 96%
CPU2 95%
CPU3 98%
CPU4 94%
```

Comment: Which version of the Nvidia drivers have you installed?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, NVIDIA Driver version 390.116, in Software and Updates I've nvidia-driver-390(proprietary,tested)

Comment: Recommended is 418. If not available in S&U then add the graphics drivers PPA first.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, thanks for help, I installed 418 from ppa, but sadly result still the same Nvidia Settings show that only 400-500M used during playing game

Comment: Then that's all the software needs.

Comment: You're incorrectly assuming that the GPU/CPU usage is proportional to the RAM usage and that "freezes and twitches" are because not enough RAM is used. No, it is likely to be related with a slow HDD. And the "age" of the game matters very little, what matters is its hardware requirements for Linux that are often higher than for its original version version for Windows and DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where games would refuse to run on the nVidia GPU, and would only run on the Intel HD Gfx. Not only that, but Optimus is buggy on *nix, and tends to have endless issues. There should be a way to force it to run on the nVidia GPU, but I forget how exactly I did it, as my install has a mesh of 340 and 390, as that's the only way it works. (don't even ask how, I honestly don't know how I did it.)